# Sumar valores de tres tablas, y mostrarlos en una sola

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tengo tres tablas con la columna Código como comun:

Tabla 1

```
| Codigo| Valor 1|
| ---------------| ------------- |
| 1      | 50    |
| 2      | 50    |
| 3      | 50    |
```

Tabla 2

```
| Codigo| Valor 2|
| -------------- | ------------- |
| 1      | 50    |
| 1      | 50    |
| 2      | 50    |
| 2      | 50    |
| 3      | 50    |
| 3      | 50    |
```

Tabla 3

```
| Codigo| Valor 3|
| -------------- | ------------- |
| 1      | 50    |
| 1      | 50    |
| 1      | 50    |
| 2      | 50    |
| 2      | 50    |
| 2      | 50    |
| 3      | 50    |
| 3      | 50    |
| 3      | 50    |
```

Necesito hacer la suma de las tres tablas y las muestre en una sola, lo estoy haciendo de esta manera:

```
$sql_select = $pdo->query("SELECT tabla1.valor, tabla2.valor, tabla3.valor FROM tabla1,tabla2,tabla3 WHERE tabla1.codigo=tabla2=codigo GROUP BY tabla1.do_operativo");
```

Se supóne, o al menos necesito, que el resultado sea este:

| Codigo | Valor 1 sumado | Valor 2 sumado | Valor 3 sumado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 100 | 150 |
| 2 | 50 | 100 | 150 |
| 3 | 50 | 100 | 150 |

Pero me está devolviendo esto:

| Codigo | Valor 1 sumado | Valor 2 sumado | Valor 3 sumado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 200 | 450 |
| 2 | 50 | 200 | 450 |
| 3 | 50 | 200 | 450 |

Es como si se multiplicara con la cantidad de filas de la tabla 3. Me podría ayudar para saber donde estoy fallando. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola. Tu pregunta no se entiende y en la consulta no veo que estés sumando nada. Por favor pulsa en [edit] y clarifica el problema y lo que quieres lograr exactamente.

Answer (score 2):

Te propongo esta solución:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT codigo,SUM(valor1) valor1
      FROM tabla1
      GROUP BY 1
  ) c1 JOIN (
    SELECT codigo,SUM(valor2) valor2
      FROM tabla2
      GROUP BY 1
  ) c2 USING(codigo) JOIN (
    SELECT codigo,SUM(valor3) valor3
      FROM tabla3
      GROUP BY 1
  ) c3 USING(codigo);
```

A partir del dataset que facilitas:

```
CREATE TABLE tabla1(
  codigo int,
  valor1 int
  );
CREATE TABLE tabla2(
  codigo int,
  valor2 int
  );
CREATE TABLE tabla3(
  codigo int,
  valor3 int
  );
INSERT INTO tabla1 (codigo, valor1) VALUES
(1,50),
(2,50),
(3,50);
INSERT INTO tabla2 (codigo, valor2) VALUES
(1,50),
(1,50),
(2,50),
(2,50),
(3,50),
(3,50);
INSERT INTO tabla3 (codigo, valor3) VALUES
(1,50),
(1,50),
(1,50),
(2,50),
(2,50),
(2,50),
(3,50),
(3,50),
(3,50);
```

Obtendrás el resultado que planteas:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| codigo | valor1 | valor2 | valor3 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|      1 |     50 |    100 |    150 |
|      2 |     50 |    100 |    150 |
|      3 |     50 |    100 |    150 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Lo que estás intentando hacer es algo más parecido a ésto:

```
SELECT codigo,
  SUM(valor1) valor1,
  SUM(valor2) valor2,
  SUM(valor3) valor3
  FROM tabla1
  JOIN tabla2 USING(codigo)
  JOIN tabla3 USING(codigo)
  GROUP BY 1;
```

Pero no funciona porque estás juntando todos los datos y los necesitas precisamente separados en diferentes tablas para poder sumarlos.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.